# Preventing user drag on BottomSheet Support Library 23.2

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am trying to use the bottom sheet as a popup from the bottom. I need to remove the drag capability that is in the coordinator layout. I can call

```
bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
```

if I want to animate the view. I am just trying to prevent the user from dragging their finger to pull the view up.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- view and stuff... -->

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout >
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a view that shows automatically from the bottom, without the user being able to drag it, then a bottom sheet is not the right widget. Use a ViewGroup (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, ...) and set its translationY so that it is initially off screen. When you want to show it, animate the translation Y from that offset back to 0.

What you have to do is draw the view at the bottom of the screen, then when you inflate your layout, you translate it by its height off the screen.

Say your view is called "view", after inflating, you would do this:

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new     ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreDraw() {
                        view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                        view.setTranslationY(/* get the view top Y and translate to it becomes the bottom of the screen */);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Then when you want to animate, you do:

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", /* translation value calculated above */, 0);
objectAnimator.setDuration(400);
objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
objectAnimator.start();
```

Comment: I have tried that before but I ran into issues with it not drawing the view off screen.

Comment: Ill try this and let you know! Thanks for the post.

Comment: If your view is anchored to the bottom of the screen, the translationY is simply the view height.